# Install Android 3.0 Market on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-3.0-honeycomb

Has anyone installed Android 3.0 Market on an emulator?  I have been adapting some instructions I found so they would work on Honeycomb.  Almost there ... take a look.  Step 8 has a problem, as you can see.  Suggestions?
http://slinnbooks.com/books/android/accessing-android-market-from-android-sdk.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix the problem with the command below:

```
emulator -memory 1024 -avd MotorolaXoom -partition-size 512 -scale .75
```

But it is not working here. You can install Android Market, but when you reboot the emulator, everything is cleared. I think it is related to the version of the SDK.

So, don't upgrade the Android SDK.

If you manage to install Android Market successfully, please share your SDK (r08) with me.